# Smooth Player Ball Rolling - Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to achieve this kind of player ball movement:
[Catch Up (Ketchapp)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SN2fi7_qlXk)

From my side I have tried and record a video of my current implementation:
[CatchUpBallMovementDemo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YN19KaaVmfQ35taSEbXBocmfJl3_YED9)

Two kinds of problem, I was facing:

1. ball making so much jerk while moving on the plain track that I hope you have clearly noticed in my recorded video
2. when ball reach left or right edge and you try to swipe its making jerk again rather than remain restricted because clamping related code already added

I have just created a demo project so here I am providing the link for it so personally you can check and provide me a suggestion for making ball movement perfect.

Demo Project Source Link: [CatchUpBallDemo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sZ4CkSrpuHIaZyn9aSPNRoGN7nOyxcrZ)

**Demo Project SIZE 20MB**

What at present making jerk in ball movement that I can't able to decide, whether its following camera jerk, whether ball not moving properly though I have created a plain track for checking purpose.

Ball Inspector Detail:
[image]

Complete code added within the working demo project. Share your suggestions with me to solve this.

Code Scripts:
**BallController**

```c#
[RequireComponent (typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class BallController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //
    private Rigidbody myRigidBody;
    private bool isJumper;
    private bool allowSpeedIncrease;
    private BallInputHandler ballInputHandler;
    private float speed;
    private float speedMilestone;
    private float jumpCounter;
    private float scoreElapsedTime;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool isGrounded;

    //
    public float ballHorzRange;
    public float ballStartSpeed;
    public float ballTopSpeed;
    public float smoothnessValue;
    public float smoothnessX;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        DoOnAwake ();
    }

    private void DoOnAwake ()
    {
        ballInputHandler = GetComponent<BallInputHandler> ();
        myRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        speed = ballStartSpeed;
        speedMilestone = ballStartSpeed;
    }

    public void Start ()
    {
        DoOnStart ();
    }

    private void DoOnStart ()
    {
        // assinging player transform to camera to follow
        Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow> ().FollowPlayer (transform);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        // slowly increase ball moving speed
        if (allowSpeedIncrease) {

            speed += Time.deltaTime;

            if (speed >= speedMilestone) {
                allowSpeedIncrease = false;
                speed = speedMilestone;
            }
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // do jumping
        if (isJumper) {
            jumpCounter++;
            if (jumpCounter >= 3) {
                isJumper = false;
                jumpCounter = 0;
            }
            myRigidBody.AddForce (Vector3.up * 700f);
        }


        // applying continuous forward velocity
        Vector3 nextVelocity = myRigidBody.velocity;
        nextVelocity.x = ballInputHandler.horizontalInput * smoothnessX;
        nextVelocity.z = speed;

        if (isGrounded) {
            nextVelocity.y = 0;
        } else if (!isJumper) {
            nextVelocity.y -= speed * 0.1f;
        }

        myRigidBody.velocity = nextVelocity.normalized * speed;

        ClampingBallMovement ();
    }

    // ball horizontal movement limitation
    private void ClampingBallMovement ()
    {
        Vector3 currRigidbodyPos = myRigidBody.position;

        if (currRigidbodyPos.x <= -ballHorzRange || currRigidbodyPos.x >= ballHorzRange) {
            currRigidbodyPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (currRigidbodyPos.x, -ballHorzRange, ballHorzRange);
            myRigidBody.position = currRigidbodyPos;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag (GameConstants.TAG_TRACK_SPAWNER)) {
            GameController.Instance.SpawnPlateform ();
        } else if (other.CompareTag (GameConstants.TAG_TRACK_DESTROYER)) {
            Destroy (other.transform.parent.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

**BallMeshRolling**

```c#
public class BallMeshRolling : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 ballLastPosition;


    void Start ()
    {
        ballLastPosition = transform.parent.position;
    }

    void Update ()
    {

        // implementation-1
        float speed = Vector3.Distance (transform.parent.position, ballLastPosition) * 30f;
        transform.RotateAround (transform.position, Vector3.right, speed);

        //      float dragDifference = (transform.position.x - ballLastPosition.x) * 30f;
        //      transform.RotateAround (transform.position, Vector3.forward, dragDifference);

        ballLastPosition = transform.parent.position;
    }
}
```

**CameraFollow**

```c#
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

    //
    private Vector3 newPos;
    private Vector3 initialPosition;

    //
    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offSet;

    void Awake ()
    {
        initialPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate ()
    {
        if (!player)
            return;

        newPos = player.position + offSet;
        newPos.x = ReMap (newPos.x);
        newPos.y = Mathf.Clamp (newPos.y, initialPosition.y, initialPosition.y + 1f);
        //      transform.position = newPos;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, newPos, 10f * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    public void FollowPlayer (Transform target)
    {
        player = target;
        ResetCamera ();
    }

    public float ReMap (float value, float from1 = -4f, float to1 = 4f, float from2 = -2.5f, float to2 = 2.5f)
    {
        return (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;
    }

    public void ResetCamera ()
    {
        transform.position = initialPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, so I don't have to download your source?

Comment: Demo Project I have provided because I want to mention all things clearly - specially ball parent and child related technique - that I try to mention through above image ... Let me put here main scripts source code.

Comment: Demo project is just 20mb size - I have just included ball movement in it...

Comment: I'm on a smartphone so I'm out I guess .. but it seems that you clamp **after** applying the touch input. You should already restrict this before when getting the input values. And to the first problem: it might appear maybe because the ball rotation doesn't match with the movement speed to this might produce some sort of friction with the plane?

Comment: @derHugo I think sir you are on right track - give this little of your more time when you sit in front of computer - I really need help into this because I was trying from couple of days...

Comment: Any suggestions into this ??

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the second problem by simply adding this to `BallController.ClampingBallMovement()`:

```c#
private void ClampingBallMovement ()
{
    Vector3 currRigidbodyPos = myRigidBody.position;

    if (currRigidbodyPos.x <= -ballHorzRange || currRigidbodyPos.x >= ballHorzRange) {
        currRigidbodyPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (currRigidbodyPos.x, -ballHorzRange, ballHorzRange);
        myRigidBody.position = currRigidbodyPos;
    }


    // I ADDED THIS
    // Clamp the velocity as well
    if (currRigidbodyPos.x <= -ballHorzRange && myRigidBody.velocity.x < 0 || currRigidbodyPos.x >= ballHorzRange && myRigidBody.velocity.x > 0)
    {
        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(0, myRigidBody.velocity.y, myRigidBody.velocity.z);
    }

}
```

you clamped the position but did not clamp the velocity as well.

I could not reproduce the first `jerking` arround on my PC.

Comment: That jerking was only get generated on mobile device on my PC also its working properly but on mobile its behaving like a video --- specially device with 1 GB ram its not running properly though its just ball movement thing

Comment: I got confused with the mobile-only problem because on PC its showing no issue...

Comment: do you get any exceptions on the mobile device?

Comment: I have 1 GB and 2GB devices and in both its showing problem - No there is no exception in Log its clear and perfect because its just ball rolling related demo project.

Comment: Sir if you have Andriod phone then install demo project build into that - so that you can understand my point clearly ...

Comment: I have not really the ambition to install and configure AndroidStudio + SDK again on my PC right now. What I can say so far is that there might be an issue with the frequently spawning of the large track object and the fast movement? Apparently even on the PC it takes a few frames until the new track is rendered correctly. Maybe the physics needs time to get to a good quality as well?

Comment: I can't say NO to your above point but as per my understanding, we are just doing player movement and I have created a track using Unity inbuilt 3d cube object...so this may not be a performance issue in mobile

Comment: yes but I can see on pc that the new spawned objects have a "bad" quality right after spawn and actually are reaching the good quality when the ball already passed half of it ... maybe something in the quality settings or alternatively: Don't spawn new objects but let them there the whole time, just change the position?

Comment: Basically, it's my track traveling related game, I have designed 28 different patterns on these tracks so I can't able to use same and repeat it.

Comment: I think I can kind of confirm at least for the pc that reducing the Quality in the QualitySettings from Ultra (current value) to something smaller, the rendering is still a good quality but doesn't require this caching time anymore + the ball now dosn't "jump" anymore ... sometimes it actually did "jerk" a tiny bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182157/discussion-between-siddharth-and-derhugo).